# Alignment of inline bar labels

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

Does anyone know how to left-align inline labels (Task 3 & Task 4)?

[image: example]

The code below, from an older manual version, does not work:

Code:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, inline,]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2014}{12} \\

\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{3}
\ganttbar[bar inline label node/.style={above=3pt}]{Task 2}{5}{10} \\ 
\ganttbar[bar inline label node/.style={left}]{Task 3}{2}{7} \\
\ganttbar[bar inline label node/.style={left}]{Task 4}{2}{15} 
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Final task}{11}{12} 

\end{ganttchart}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}


\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, inline,]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2014}{12} \\

\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{3}
\ganttbar[bar inline label node/.style={above=3pt}]{Task 2}{5}{10} \\
\ganttbar[bar inline label node/.style={anchor=west},bar inline label anchor=west]{Task 3}{2}{7} \\
\ganttbar[bar inline label node/.style={anchor=west},bar inline label anchor=west]{Task 4}{2}{15}
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Final task}{11}{12}

\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]